# java sorting in alphabetical order

Tags: java

I am attempting to sort a list of names in alphabetical order and I keep getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException and I don't know why.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class alphabeticalOrder {

 static String names[];
 static int count = 0;
 static String sorting;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String[] names = new String[500];

  File namesFile = new File("names.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(namesFile);

  while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = inputFile.nextLine();
   String[] namesDetails = line.split("     ");
   names[count] = namesDetails[0];
   count++;
  }

  sort();

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));

 }

 public static void sort() {

  int namesLength = names.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < namesLength - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < namesLength - 1; j++) {
    if (names[j].compareTo(names[j - 1]) > 0) {
     sorting = names[j - 1];
     names[j - 1] = names[j];
     names[j] = sorting;
    }
   }
  }

 }

}
```

Customers txt has these names

```
Smith, Alexandra

Downes, Trish

Akbal, Maria
```

and the array must equal 500

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (names[j].compareTo(names[j - 1]) > 0) {
```

to

```
if (names[j] != null && names[j].compareTo(names[j - 1]) > 0) {
```

And the annoying null pointer exception will go away.

If you ever get over your 500 String array obsession I suggest you try TreeSet since it will do all the sorting work for you.

[image: Cheat Sheet]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<String> alphabetical = new TreeSet<String>();
    alphabetical.add("A");
    alphabetical.add("Z");
    alphabetical.add("M");

    System.out.println(alphabetical);
}
```

outputs: [A, M, Z]

Comment: I tried both ways and am still having the error

Comment: On exactly what line?

Comment: if (names[j] != null && names[j].compareTo(names[j - 1]) > 0) { this and the sort part in the main method where i have the method sort()

Comment: If you haven't simply forgotten to compile like this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816776/java-short-circuit-evaluation then do a System.out.println(names[j] + "<- names[j]")//TODO remove.  Put it just before the if.

Comment: I am doing that and I am still getting the error and I have no idea why because it looks right but just won't compile

Comment: Does it display the names[j] + "<- names[j]" line once or 500x500 times?  -- Wait a minute, won't compile?  Null pointer exception is a run time error not a compiler error.  What are you really seeing?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at final_practice.alphabeticalOrder.sort(alphabeticalOrder.java:46)
 at final_practice.alphabeticalOrder.main(alphabeticalOrder.java:35) this is what i am seeing

Comment: That's no compiler error.  Did you add the <- names[j] line?  Did you recompile successfully after adding it? When you rerun the code did it display? What did it display?

Comment: it says the exact same thing . This is what you ment rite  public static void sort()
 {
  
  int namesLength = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < namesLength; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < namesLength; j++) {
      System.out.println(names[j] + "<- names[j]");     
      if(names[j] != null && names[j].compareTo(names[j - 1]) > 0) { 
       sorting = names[j - 1];
       names[j - 1] = names[j];
       names[j] = sorting;

      }
     }
    }
   }

Comment: Then you didn't add the line, didn't add it before the error, or you didn't recompile. And yes that's what I meant.  Try adding a System.out.println("Hello World"); at the very start of your code.  If it works move it down until it doesn't.  If it doesn't work you're not compiling like you think you are.

Comment: it works everywhere but inside the if statement

Comment: Well if Hello World works outside the if then System.out.println(names[j] + "<- names[j]"); will work outside the if.  Run it just before the if and tell me what you see.  Scroll up to find its output if you have to.

Comment: nothing comes up just the null pointer error

Comment: It should be displaying `null <- names[j]` at least.  If you're telling me switching from Hello World to the debugging code magically makes it stop displaying then you've got me at a loss because I've just tested that code on my end at it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `names` array has 500 elements, most of which are null. That's why you are getting `NullPointerException`, when you call `names[j].compareTo()` for a null reference.

You should only attempt to sort as many names as you get as input.

Instead of

```
int namesLength = names.length;
```

Try

```
int namesLength = count;
```

Since `count` holds the number of inputs you actually have.

BTW, your sort() method has other problems :

1. The loops should go from 0 to namesLength - 1, so the condition should be `j < namesLength`
2. `names [j-1]` would give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when j==0

Answer (score 0):

You have the array in size `500` and number your names are `6`.

when you assign six names to first six indexes of the array, the rest indexes are still having `null` value. Therefor, comparing with the null value will throw `NullPointerException`.

**why**?

Because **Objects in Java initialized** by `null` value when they are defined for the first time.

**Suggestion** :

Try to use `ArrayList` which shrinks and expands by itself